# Как центрировать блок по центру?

Tags: html, css

Как разместить блок div с классом "tabs" по центру?

```css
   .tabs {
display: flex;
min-width: 980px;
min-height: 93px;
border-bottom: 4px solid #E7E7E7;
/*background-color: black;*/
margin-top: 156px;
}

.tabOne {
min-height: 43px;
min-width: 170px;
}

.tabTwo {
min-width: 258px;
min-height: 43px;
}

.tabTree {
min-width: 268px;
min-height: 43px;
}

.circle {
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
background: #5F5F5F;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
}

.circle2 {
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
background: #5F5F5F;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
}

.circle3 {
width: 43px;
height: 43px;
background: #5F5F5F;
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
}

.circle:hover {
background-color: #ADD136;
}

.circle2:hover {
background-color: #ADD136;
}

.circle3:hover {
background-color: #ADD136;
}

.one {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.two {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.tree {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="tabs" >
        <!-- tabOne -->
            <div class="tabOne" >
                <div class="circle" >
                    <p class="one" >1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /tabOne -->

        <!-- tabTwo -->
            <div class="tabTwo" >
                <div class="circle2" >
                    <p class="two" >2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /tabTwo -->

        <!-- tabTree -->
            <div class="tabTree" >
                <div class="circle3" >
                    <p class="tree" >3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- /tabTree -->

        </div>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Гуглите align...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. у табс выставлена минимальная ширина, значит на десктопах данный блок будет по ширине 100%.
2. устанавливаем ширину, делаем через `width` или `max-width`
3. после устанавливаем параметр `margin:0 auto`, что позволяет разместить блок по центру.

```css
     .tabs {
        display: flex;
        max-width: 980px;
        min-height: 93px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #E7E7E7;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }
```